# Erasing first 50 value from the array and re-size it

Tags: java

I have a byte array, I am trying to erase first 50 elements of the array. I mean by erase that after erasing the array its size will be less than original one. I have two questions;

- How can I do that in a time efficient manner ?
- I think it is not possible that re-size array by java native method, am I wrong ? I have searched but I couldnot find.

Comment: You cannot resize an array. Use a `LinkedList`.

Comment: *"I think it is not possible that re-size array by java native method, am I wrong ?"* - No.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Perhaps you could comment on the efficiency of a `List<Byte>` compared with a `byte[]` ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I could indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to copy it - there are several ways to do it, [for example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29):

```
byte[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalArray, 50, originalArray.length);
```

Alternatively you can use a list and call [the `subList` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) which avoids the copy.

Comment: when I compile it gives `cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Arrays
location: class receiver
` this error. ?

Comment: @user2353516 You have to import it.

Comment: @user2353516 You need to `import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 1):

Array SIZES are not mutable. You must create a new array with the proper size you need and copy the info you want over. You can do this or use an arraylist which is mutable.

Comment: I do not think an `ArrayList` resizes when becoming smaller. It also uses an array below the covers.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis though I can't find any supporting info either way online right now I am almost 100% sure it does. If you could provide something it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the only supporting info I can find is the Java API site which leans toward my conclusion http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: It's kind of hard to post it here, but the `ArrayList` source code for the `remove(int)` method does a `System.arraycopy()` to the same object array (different indices obviously). I don't see anything in that method that resizes it.

Comment: That's what I was commenting about. With an `ArrayList`, you will still have the empty array `[]` positions. With a `LinkedList`, you will only ever have one dangling pointer to the `null` `next` object.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a ByteBuffer if you want efficiency.  This allows you to create a large buffer and move the start and the end to erase, compact or grow the buffer later.

Answer (score 1):

Q. I think it is not possible that re-size array by java native method, am I wrong ? I have searched but I could not find.
A. You can't remove an element from Array but set the value of the element to empty or null. But that is why there are other efficient collentions such as LinkedList, ArrayList, Vectors..

Q. How can I do that in a time efficient manner?
A. You would need two arrays. Look at the code below:

What it does is copy the remaining content in second array.. in a efficient way

```
public int[] removeElement(int[] array, int del)
{
    int[] result = new int[array.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, 0, del);
    if (array.length != del)
    {
        System.arraycopy(array, del + 1, result, del, array.length - del - 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize an array but you can copy it into a smaller array.

```
public int[] schrink(int[] input) {
return Arrays.copyOfRange(input, 49, input.length-50);
}
```